# Batch File to search for a directory up the current directory tree

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find a directory which exists above the current directory and batch syntax is making me go blind.  So for example, say I'm in:

c:\dev\projects\folder1\projectname\batch.bat

I would like to find my shared libs folder which resides here:

c:\dev\shared

I need to then set this as a variable I can reuse.  I was doing the following but I feel like I've reached the stage where butting my head against the wall is not worth it anymore:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set shareddir=%~dp0
:loop
  set shareddir=!shareddir!..\
  set sharedir2=!shareddir!shared\    
if not exists (%sharedir2%) goto loop
ECHO shareddir found = %sharedir2%
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your method return a path *relative* to the Batch file's one like this:

```
c:\dev\projects\folder1\projectname\..\..\..\shared
```

Try this method instead:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
:loop
   cd ..
   if not exist shared goto loop
set sharedDir=%cd%\shared
popd
ECHO shareddir found = %sharedDir%
```

Comment: +1, But some quotes around the assignment would be good to protect against special chars. Also, the code will become an infinite loop if shared cannot be found.

Comment: Works and is concise, I did not try the other solutions.  Infinite loop was not a problem for me (prefer the conciseness in my batch script).

Answer (score 0):

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set shareddir=%~dp0
:loop
  set shareddir=!shareddir!..\
  set sharedir2=!shareddir!shared\
if not exist "!sharedir2!" goto loop
ECHO shareddir found = !sharedir2!
endlocal
```

In this case there's no need of delayed expansion , but anyway...
to check existence use `IF EXIST` but not `if exists`  (command prompt does not care about gramar :-) ) and use quotes instead of brackets (it's needed for paths with empty spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it. I've added an additional test to prevent an infinite loop if the shared folder cannot be found.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sharedDir=%~dp0"
:loop
for %%F in ("%sharedDir%\..") do if not exist "%%~fF\shared" (
  if %sharedDir% neq %%~fF (
    set "sharedDir=%%~fF"
    goto :loop
  ) else set "sharedDir="
) else set "sharedDir=%%~fF\shared"

:: Display the value. It will be undefined if shared folder not found.
set sharedDir
```